# Is there a way in Terminal to highlight the row under the cursor?

Tags: terminal, productivity

I need to read a long row of output in Terminal and was wondering if there is a way to have the whole row where the mouse cursor is positioned highlighted. Alternatively, would there be a way to highlight a row and control the highlight with the keyboard?

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify (if necessary) I'm looking for an equivalent to row highlighting in Excel (less the column highlight) as provided in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349424/ddg#22350417

Comment: You can use a 'cursor guide' from the iTerm2 app.
See: https://superuser.com/questions/1336511/iterm-window-highlighted-on-the-current-line

Answer (score 1):

Yes - just put the cursor on the line and triple click it - and it will light up the whole line.  It works with apple terminal as well as iTerm.

Comment: I was looking for a solution that is easier to use, such as hovering over a line or using the keyboard's up and down arrows to highlight that line. The problem with triple clicking is that you can not easily move between lines in the way up and down keys or a hovering would do, because you'd have to redo triple clicking for every line. // Thanks for offering to search the *.rc files for what sets that. Maybe there's something in there...

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is not much better than dragging the cursor over the whole line.  I do it and then use cut/paste to move it.  But I am old-school - started on tty's before mice were "created"... no it was before that - started with punched cards.  (1964) - this article has some ideas already built in: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/23/keyboard-shortcuts-to-navigate-select-text-mac-os-x/

Answer (score -1):

On my computer, I can use the mouse to position a cursor and with mouse key depressed highlight whatever lines I like. I can then move the highlighted region to wherever lines I want. A lot like triple clicking but it can highlight multiple lines.